# How to resolve mvn variables?

Tags: variables, maven

Two questions in one:

1. Given a variable `${project.build.directory}`, how can i find out what exactly this resolves to on my machine?
2. Where can i find a list of all maven variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to know to which it is expanded simply do a:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

The existing list of variables can be found in the [documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) or [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide).